# flask-bcrypt: check password method always return "Type error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, bcrypt, password-hash

I'm using falsk-bcrypt and mysql connector to connect to mySQL database. 
Everything looks good when I sign up in my website and store the hashed password. When I'm log in and check the user password input and compare it to the hashed password using `bcrypt.check_password_hash()`  it always return different errors such as:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

or when I change the parameters in the `bcrypt.check_password_hash()`method

I've tried to decode the hashed password before it stored in the database and here what I got in my database:

```
$2b$12$t4uE4WxdWWv5pbNNF5Njk.viBxx/3AGYJx3aUxL20kH9cb0jTfqf2
```

My password column is varchar(100) and I used `tinytext()` and the same problem appear.

Also I tried to convert the hashed password and the user input password to strings using `str()` method.

Here is the code to insert the password (sign up page) :

```py
@app.route('/sign_up' , methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sign_up():
    form = register_form() # imported from forms.py file as a class
    db.connect()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        first_name = form.first_name.data
        last_name = form.last_name.data
        email = form.email.data
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        cur.execute("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='%s'", (email))
        email_exsist = cur.fetchone()
        if email_exsist:

            flash ('email is already exisist','danger')
        else :    

            cur.execute('INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name,email,password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)''',(first_name, last_name, email, hashed_password) )
            db.commit()
            flash(f'Account Successfully created for {form.first_name.data + " " + form.last_name.data} !' , 'success' )

            return redirect(url_for('sign_up'))
            cur.close()

    return render_template('sign_up.html' , title='Sign up' , form= form)
```

and here is the checking if statement in the (sign in page):

```py
@app.route('/login' , methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    form = login_form()# imported from forms.py file as a class
    email = form.email.data
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        cur.execute("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email =%s", [email])
        user_email = cur.fetchone()
        cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email =%s",[email])
        hashed_password = cur.fetchone()
        if user_email and bcrypt.check_password_hash( hashed_password,form.password.data) :
            login_user(user_email,remember=form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else :
            flash ('Unable to log in , please check your email and password', 'danger')

    return render_template('login.html' , title='login' , form= form)
```

Is there anything to put on app.config or convert?

Comment: can you show full `trace`?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar what do you mean by trace 
also i have solved it 
the problem was the hashed password i was taken from the db is dictionary so i have to access it first 
thanks